# What is the use of Breakpoint in slick slider?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am trying to implement a slick slider on my page. While going through the slick documentation they've mentioned that to use slider in a responsive way, follow the code (which I have posted below). I couldn't understand the use of break point. Can anyone explain me the code. I tried googling but didn't find the solution. I have pasted my code below, please go through.

```
$('.responsive').slick({
 dots: true,
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 4,
responsive: [
  {
  breakpoint: 1024,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
  },
  {
  breakpoint: 600,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
  },
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}
// You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
// settings: "unslick"
// instead of a settings object
 ]
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The breakpoints refer to the screen width to trigger the logic of the following `settings` at. Specifically, they will trigger **up to** the specified value (in pixels).

In your above example, this correlates to the following:

- 480px and narrower: 1 slide is shown
- 481px to 600px: 2 slides are shown
- 601px to 1024px: 3 slides are shown (with infinite looping)
- 1025px and wider: 4 slides are shown